# Why does the DropDownListFor helper fail after a validation error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, html.dropdownlistfor

Been at this for too long! any advice on the following problem...

code added:

Model: AccountModels.cs

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Select role: ")]
public String Role { get; set; }
```

Controller: AccountController.cs

```
  // GET: /Account/Register

public ActionResult Register()
{ 
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    SelectListItem item; 
    foreach (String role in Roles.GetAllRoles()) 
    { 
        item = new SelectListItem { Text = role, Value = role }; 
        list.Add(item); 
    }
    ViewBag.roleList = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)list;
    return View();
}
```

Also in the [HTTpPost]

```
if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
{
    Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Role);

    MailClient.SendWelcome(model.Email);
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
    return RedirectToAction("Create", "Customers");
}
```

View: Register.cshtml

```
<div class="editor-label">      
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role)  
</div>      
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, ViewBag.roleList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

The code works and allows the user to select a role but falls apart if the user breaks validation rules when creating a new account.

Example: if the passwords don't match normally validation would kick in but due to the addition of the new code the application just crashes.

The code which creates the error:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, ViewBag.roleList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Error code

> The ViewData item that has the key 'Role' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Comment: is this error happens in your httppost when validation fails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have this problem occuring when in your HttpPost action method where your Validation fails. and i believe you have `return View()` statement in your HttpPost action method. When you return the View again, your ViewData is null. So you need to reload the data again for the dropdown

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
 //If validation ok, save
 if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
 {
   //dio stuff
 }
 else
 { 
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    SelectListItem item; 
    foreach (String role in Roles.GetAllRoles()) 
    { 
        item = new SelectListItem { Text = role, Value = role }; 
        list.Add(item); 
    }
    ViewBag.roleList = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)list; 
    return View();
 }
}
```

Ideally, I would not use the ViewData to hande this. I will have my ViewModel to handle this.

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
 public string FirstName { set;get;} 
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
 public int SelectedRoleId { get; set; }
}
```

and in your get action call,pass the ViewModel back to your View.

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
  RegisterViewModel objViewModel=new RegisterViewModel();
  objViewModel.Roles=GetAllRolesAs();  // returns the list of roles to this property
  return View(objViewModel);
}
```

Make your View a strongly typed one

```
@model RegisterViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)

   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedRoleId,new SelectList(Model.Roles , "Value","Text"),   "Select Role")
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

and in your HttpPostAction, Receive this ViewModel object as the parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel objVM)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //Check your custom validation also
    if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
    {
          //Save and then Redirect

    }
    else
    {
      objVM.Roles=GetAllRolesAs(); // get the list of roles here again because HTTP is stateless
    }
  }  
 return View(objVM);
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but same error when validation is broke?

Comment: @DazaAza: Where are you getting the errors ?When you load the view again ? Use break points in Visualstudio to make sure that the data you returned has proper value

Comment: @DazaAza: I updated my answer to use the strongly typed views.

Comment: Do you create new model or put it in with the AccountModels

Comment: ViewModels are not Models. It may have some properties iike the Entity Model. But ViewModels are specific to handle the view. It does not matter where you keep them. I keep them in a folder called `ViewModels`.